# how to fixe Groovy dependency issue?

Tags: java, groovy

I use maven to manage all my dependency and in my Groovy test class have some imports, when i run make-ejb-module in Intellij 13 i get following error which shows that groovy can't find my imports.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion or help.

```
ERROR in C:\development\j2ee\ejbapps\bdc\testsrc\test\TestPersistPrice.groovy (at line 19)
[ERROR] import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] Groovy:unable to resolve class org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord
```

I tried this but no effect.

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.commons', module='commons-csv', version='1.2')
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
```

Comment: Intellij 13? That's a few years outdated... Anyways, are you sure that that class exists in the version of the library you've downloaded?

Comment: Yes it is there, because i can run the application. i also opened it and checked it. also in the code i can refer to his all methods.

Comment: Does you have idea integration module for maven enabled?